# Is it possible to set a custom serializer for an area in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am trying to configure an area to use some custom JSON serializer settings for a newly created area in an ASP.Net project. I am writing a Web API controller.

Unfortunately, I cannot affect the entire project (lots of legacy code), else I would have just done:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
json.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() { new StringEnumConverter() };
```

But I can change this new area however I see fit.

Is it possible to configure this one new area (there are other areas I don't want affected, as well) in a similar way as the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a class which inherits from `JsonResult`.Write the logic to implement the desired serializer inside this class.
2. Create a base controller class and override the `Json` method to return your custom `JsonResult`.
3. Lastly, change all the controllers inside your area to inherit from the custom `BaseController`

**Example:**

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new MySpecialJsonResult //Inherits from JsonResult and contains the desired serializer implementation
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
        };
    }
}

public class EmployeeController : BaseController
{
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        //Your custom serializer will be used...
        return Json(new{Text="Hello"},JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever! Currently, the actions have signatures that are typed, not just `JsonResult`; is there so rather than returning `JsonResult`, they're returning `IEnumerable<thing>`; can this be adapted to work similarly?

Comment: You said JSON serializer in your question, hence the answer.How can you have actions that return IEnumerable<T>?Are you using MVC or web api?

Comment: Apparently, the controller was started in Web API. I did not realize that while drafting the post. My controllers were just routes like `public async Task<ApiResponse<IEnumerable<string>>> GetMessages()` and such.

Comment: Apparently, areas are being faked through many layers of configuration. If this was actually using an MVC controller, this is the proper answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, having `JsonResult` as a response type doesn't work well with Swagger